# 7zip resume archiving after interruption ( command line )

Tags: windows, 7-zip, archiving

I try to 7z the entire disk on windows, using 7zip. I do simple like this: `7z.exe a Z:\DriveBackupOct15.7z D:\`

After a while process interrupted due to "System Error", because i accidently detached the disk. I have a question, the archive was created but it is not full, how i can resume the archiving from where i ended? Something like, update existing Z:\DriveBackupOct15.7z, adding files from `D:\` which are not in the `Z:\DriveBackupOct15.7z` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. 7-Zip is designed this way.

Even if in binary mode you remove last unusable data from the archive, you will be missing file names at the end of the archive for the files that already have been added to it. File names are at the end of the archive.

You need to add the files in a uninterruptible process. Especially if this is default solid mode of archiving.